# Removing a program that apt doesn't see

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, software-uninstall, r

I have an old installation of R that I would like to get rid of and replace with a new version. However, apt doesn't see this package at all. It doesn't show up in Synaptic and running `sudo apt-get remove r-base` gives the message "Package 'r-base' is not installed, so not removed". However, the program works and `which R` shows `/usr/local/bin/R`. (As far as I remember, I originally installed this with Synaptic, but it was a few years ago, so I could be wrong.) If I just install the new version of R via Synaptic, running R from the command line still gives me the old version. How do I either get rid of the old version or make my system use a newly installed one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The binary `R` is usually placed in `/usr/bin/R` and not in `/usr/local/bin/R`. Therefore you haven't installed the package via a package manager from the standard repositories.

`/usr/bin/R` is part of the package `r-base-core`, therefore try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
```

---

Additionally check the subfolders in `/usr/local` for more `R`-stuff to remove, E.G.:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/R
```

A full list of the possibilities:

```
dpkg --listfiles r-base | sed 's/usr\//usr\/local\//'
dpkg --listfiles r-base-core | sed 's/usr\//usr\/local\//'
```

---

To use the `R` from your configured repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Comment: Manual deletion (followed by restarting Terminal) worked; thanks! I can run a normally installed version of R now.